# Estrutura de repetição que adiciona elementos em um array sem repetir elementos

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um array com o nome **produtosSelecionados**.

Preciso criar uma função que sempre que for chamada adiciona os elementos de **produtosSelecionados** para o array produtosConfirmadosAnuncio, porém o elemento não deve ser adicionado se já existir em **produtosConfirmadosAnuncio**.

Tentei algo como:

```
  adicionaProdutoConfirmadosAnuncio(){
    for(let i=0;i<this.produtosSelecionados.length;i++){
      for(let j=i+1;j<this.produtosSelecionados.length;j++){
        if(this.produtosSelecionados[i] !== this.produtosSelecionados[j]){
          this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.push(this.produtosSelecionados[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio);
  }
```

Porém dessa forma os elementos estão sendo adicionados mais de uma vez no meu array **produtosConfirmadosAnuncio**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com es6 e usando Set é possível uma solução bem mais elegante.

```
produtosConfirmadosAnuncio=new Set()

adicionaProdutoConfirmadosAnuncio(){
   this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio=new Set([...this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio, ...this. produtosSelecionados]);
}
```